# Is it possible to make this look more magical and see through?

Tags: rendering, transparency, effects

I'd like this purple shadow-thing to look more magical. I created an image in photoshop and added it to a plane as a texture, but it doesn't look quite like I want it to. Is it possible to achieve this look in blender? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by running your image through an Emission shader and then mixing That with a Transparent shader, using the image alpha as a mix factor. Then, make sure to enable "bloom" to make it glow.

[image: AlphaGlow]

Comment: why thank you very much, that did it!